# Returning map to another map

Tags: groovy

I have 2 functions in controller, as below. However i am not sure if i'm doing it right.

```
def save() {
    Map varObj = [:]
    varObj.putAll(setData(params, size))
}

def setData(data, size) {
    Map obj = [
        //Some process here
    ]
    return obj
}
```

The reason i'm doing this is because the logics in setData will be used in few functions in the controller, therefore i just create setData function and use it when its needed.

I got the obj right in the setData (i printed it and it showed the correct map), but when i tried to return the map back to save(), i got null on the varObj.

Did i pass the map correctly in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) in Map has a `void` return type. And this being the last line the method, `void` is returned. The map has to be returned explicitly.

```
def save() {
    Map varObj = [:]
    varObj.putAll(setData(params, size))
    varObj
}
```

You would like to use [`leftShift`](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#leftShift(java.util.Map)) instead to decrease the verbosity.

```
def save() {
    Map varObj = [:]
    varObj << setData(params, size)
}
```

Comment: Weird. I was sure i did the one you described above, and it didn't work. But now it worked. Thanks alot! :)